# Hyper V VM's on Windows 2012 host have no web access

Tags: switch-statement, virtual, hyper-v

Using the Hyper V role in Server 2012 to create Windows 2008 R2 VM.
Host has one NIC.

Virtual Switch was set up as below:

- set as external network
- 'allow management OS' was checked.
- switch was selected as the network adapter for the VM

At this point the host has web access (this is never an issue).

VM is launched but doesn't have web access.
Network and sharing center in VM says it is connected to an 'unidentified network' (private network).
Network discovery is on.

I have already switched the NIC on the host machine - that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Additional 01:
I just created a VM running Win7x64 OS.
Same problem.

Additional 02:
I thought that maybe I had a bad install of Server 2012 so I put a new drive in and installed the OS again. 
Did the windows updates and created a new VM by connecting to an existing VHDX file.
Same problem as before.

Comment: This should be on Serverfault SE.

Comment: Yeah and the virtual switch 'should' work, yet here we are.

Comment: I am not familiar with Hyper-V. What I am doing in VMware is that I check what type of network adapter the VM is using. If it's using NAT, then the VM should have web access right away. Sorry if I don't know the technical stuff. I'm just an ordinary user.

Answer (score 0):

I took the host server home where I would have more control over network settings.

From my router interface I found an IP address which wasn't being used.
Took this IP address and the other relevant information (default gateway and DNS servers) from the router. 
In the properties of the VM Local Area Connection, I configured the settings for the TCP/IPv4 option. I made it use a static IP address instead of it trying to fetch everything automatically.
Restarted the VM so the new IP settings would 'take'. 
Now the VM has web access.

Answer (score 0):

Sig, if you're using the VM for internal purposes only (testing, dev environment, etc.) or don't need a physical connection to the network adapter, create a internal one for the VM, share the host adapter and connect the internal to the shared adapter. I found this is the simplest & error-prone way in this excellent article from Ben Armstrong:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/09/using-hyper-v-with-a-wireless-network-adapter.aspx